# Python - How to determine whether data points are random or clustered?

Tags: python, statistics, spatial

Let's assume we are analyzing booking patterns over a month. I will give three example data-sets. I am searching for any algorithm to differentiate these on the basis of randomness.

```
data-set 1                    data-set2
day   bookings               day    bookings
1       20                    3      35 
2       11                    15     40
3       8                     22     11                   
5       31
6       19                  data-set 3
7       7                     10      20
9       15                    11      37
11      22                    12      9
12      23                    13      26
13      12
14      10
15      20
16      13
19      22
20      18
21      19
22      4
23      2
24      31
25      23
27      28
28      9 
29      13
30      27
```

Looking at the `day`"values of these data-sets by naked eye, it is clear that `data-set1 is Random, data-set2 is dispersed and data-set 3 is clustered`

My query is if there is any algorithm I could use in Python to achieve these results for extremely large data-sets.

Answer (score 1):

Just use any clustering algorithm. You have only one independent variable '`bookings`', so calculating distance shouldn't be computationally expensive. You can use `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`, for example.

And if you don't want to analyse how many clusters you need, you can use an algorithm without a priori knowledge of number of clusters, for example `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reference to DBSCAN. I have one thing to clarify. I am trying to look for randomness in the day values only. The prototype I am working on will use one formula for random x-axis (time) values and a different formula for clustered/dispersed values. is there any simpler way to just ascertain whether the collection of x-axis (day) values are random or not. For example, if we have only 3 days for which booking exists in a month, then definitely it's not random.

Comment: Of course, the second step would be to see if we have similar no. of bookings over different days. That will also change the formula. But that will come afterwards.

Comment: Hmm, I thought days were just ids for the bookings. I guess you could try 2-variables clustering with days and bookings. You can mark missing days as 0. Then you can find periods of decreased or increased bookings belonging to different clusters. Clearly, if such clusters exist, then they are not random.  In case of just 3 days, you'd have 1-2 clusters. It depends on clustering parameters. These 3 days would be either considered as outliers (i.e. random) or as forming separate cluster.